# How to create a new list or new line after a certain number of iterations

Tags: python, file, list

I have a text file that I am parsing one column of data from and the result is one big list (50 elements):

```
CLB, HNRG, LPI, MTDR, MVO, NRGY, PSE, PVR, RRC, WES, ACMP, ATLS, ATW, BP, BWP, COG, DGAS, DNR, EPB, EPL, EXLP, NOV, OIS, PNRG, SEP, APL, ARP, CVX, DMLP, DRQ, DWSN, EC, ECA, FTI, GLOG, IMO, LINE, NFX, OILT, PNG, QRE, RGP, RRMS, SDRL, SNP, TLP, VNR, XOM, XTXI, AHGP
```

Now, after every 10 elements in that list, I want a new line. So the way I though to approach it is after every 10 commas split the list into a new line, here is my approach:

```
import csv
import re

filename = input("Please enter file name to extract data from: ")
with open(filename) as f:
    next(f)
    data = f.readlines()

my_list2 = []
ticker_list = []
for line in data:
    my_list = line.split()
    my_list2.append(my_list[1])

for item in my_list2:
    ticker_list = ', '.join(my_list2)

count = 0
for item in ticker_list:
    if item == ",":
        count += 1
    if count == 10:
        ticker_list = [i.split('\n')[0] for i in ticker_list]

print (ticker_list)

##with open("ticker_data.txt", "w") as file:
##    file.write(', '.join(ticker_list))
```

But it doesn't seem to work, does anyone have a solution for me that will give me this result in a txt file:

```
CLB, HNRG, LPI, MTDR, MVO, NRGY, PSE, PVR, RRC, WES, 
ACMP, ATLS, ATW, BP, BWP, COG, DGAS, DNR, EPB, EPL, 
EXLP, NOV, OIS, PNRG, SEP, APL, ARP, CVX, DMLP, DRQ, 
DWSN, EC, ECA, FTI, GLOG, IMO, LINE, NFX, OILT, PNG, 
QRE, RGP, RRMS, SDRL, SNP, TLP, VNR, XOM, XTXI, AHGP
```

Thanks, I'm using Python 3 by the way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
import csv
from itertools import izip_longest

with open('/tmp/line.csv','r') as fin:
    cr=csv.reader(fin)
    n=10
    data=izip_longest(*[iter(list(cr)[0])]*n,fillvalue='')
    print '\n'.join(', '.join(t) for t in data)
```

With your data, prints:

```
CLB, HNRG, LPI, MTDR, MVO, NRGY, PSE, PVR, RRC, WES
ACMP, ATLS, ATW, BP, BWP, COG, DGAS, DNR, EPB, EPL
EXLP, NOV, OIS, PNRG, SEP, APL, ARP, CVX, DMLP, DRQ
DWSN, EC, ECA, FTI, GLOG, IMO, LINE, NFX, OILT, PNG
QRE, RGP, RRMS, SDRL, SNP, TLP, VNR, XOM, XTXI, AHGP
```

## Edit

With the clarification (Py 3)

I would write your program thissa way:

```
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest

n=10
with open('/tmp/rawdata.txt','r') as fin, open('/tmp/out.csv','w') as fout:
    reader=csv.reader(fin)
    writer=csv.writer(fout) 
    source=(e for line in reader for e in line)             
    for t in zip_longest(*[source]*n):
        writer.writerow(list(e for e in t if e))
```

Changes:

1. Output is to a file;
2. Source of elements is a generator;
3. No matter how many lines or comma separated elements per line, the source is treated item by item (subject to csv/element considerations);
4. No matter what `n` is, the output is `n` elements long until there is the last bit < n

Answer (score 1):

Ok Using a file called rawdata.txt that looks like this:

```
CLB, HNRG, LPI, MTDR, MVO, NRGY, PSE, PVR, RRC, WES, ACMP, ATLS, ATW, BP, BWP, COG, DGAS, DNR, EPB, EPL, EXLP, NOV, OIS, PNRG, SEP, APL, ARP, CVX, DMLP, DRQ, DWSN, EC, ECA, FTI, GLOG, IMO, LINE, NFX, OILT, PNG, QRE, RGP, RRMS, SDRL, SNP, TLP, VNR, XOM, XTXI, AHGP
```

Here is a script that reads each line and splits it into rows wih to more than 10 symbols per row

```
import csv

with open('rawdata.txt') as f:
    with open('ticker_data.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        for line in f.readlines():
            data = line.split(', ')
            chunks=[data[x:x+10] for x in xrange(0, len(data), 10)]
            for chunk in chunks:
                writer.writerow(chunk)
```

Which produces a file with this in it:

```
CLB,HNRG,LPI,MTDR,MVO,NRGY,PSE,PVR,RRC,WES
ACMP,ATLS,ATW,BP,BWP,COG,DGAS,DNR,EPB,EPL
EXLP,NOV,OIS,PNRG,SEP,APL,ARP,CVX,DMLP,DRQ
DWSN,EC,ECA,FTI,GLOG,IMO,LINE,NFX,OILT,PNG
QRE,RGP,RRMS,SDRL,SNP,TLP,VNR,XOM,XTXI,AHGP
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer so instead of printing it writes to a txt/csv file?

Comment: I keep getting this error TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface at this line writer.writerow(chunk)

Comment: This works for me, but it makes the result like ['TICKER', 'ETC'] when I need just TICKER, ETC
http://pastebin.com/uDnzjqhu

Comment: What Python are you using? I keep getting this error TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer at line writer.writerow(chunk) interface in Python 3.3

Comment: I believe you and the other poster are both using Python 2 because I googled the error and it seems to be a Python 2/3 change issue which I can't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use slices and xrange:

```
import csv
writer = csv.writer(open("output.txt", "w"))

for x in xrange(0,len(ticker_list),10):
    writer.writerow(ticker_list[x:x+10])
```

`xrange` gives us the numbers between 0 and the length of list with step size 10, then we print out a slice of length 10 starting at each of these indicies to `csvfile`. `csv.writer` will take care of adding the comma delimiters etc.

Comment: I receive this error: NameError: name 'csvfile' is not defined, what exactly should I put where it says csvfile, I'm only using .txt files and only want .txt files by the way

Comment: a csv is essentially just a comma delimited txt file. the variable `csvfile` is where the name of your output file would go, ill edit it for clarity

Comment: Is this for python 3? I am getting this error now, TypeError: argument 1 must have a "write" method. Is this what you mean: writer = csv.writer(open("ticker_data.txt", "w"))

Comment: yup that is what i meant, sorry, csv.writer wants an open filehandle, not a file name

Comment: And finally, I get this error lol NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined

Comment: really? what python are you using? just use `range` instead

Comment: I'm using Python 3 and when I use range the output is a blank txt file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32598/discussion-between-goose-and-qwwqwwq)